# Getting error even if all modules are installed

Tags: python

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 8>()
      4 import os
      6 path = 'samples' # Path for samples already taken
----> 8 recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() # Local Binary Patterns Histograms
      9 detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
     10 #Haar Cascade classifier is an effective object detection approach

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See where the code says `import os`? What do you think is the purpose of that? Given that `cv2` is someone else's code, which you had to install - do you suppose that it might be necessary to do something similar? Also, did you try to read the documentation for cv2, or follow a tutorial or quick-start guide?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.